# SignalR HubConnectionBuilder Generates HTTP 415 Error

Tags: angular, signalr.client, http-status-code-415

Setup:

- Angular 10 web app
- Net Core Web API app

On my laptop, my signalR app works just fine over **websockets**.

Once deployed to a standalone server over **SSE**, the HubConnectionBuilder/Start(), generates a 415 Unsupported Media Type on my POST request.[image: angular 10 web app log]

For some reason, the request header sets the content-type to **plain text**.

[image: request header details]

Here's my code:
[image]

Can anyone explain why i'm getting a 415 on a server (SSE)?  Do I need to override the request header?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my bug by adjusting the server configuration.  As it turned out, the app service was not configured for web sockets.  Here's how you go about updating the app service.

1. In Azure, on the app service, navigate: **Settings**>>**Configuration**[image: app service navigation]
2. On the Configuration menu, select **General Settings**[image: General Settings menu]
3. Scroll down to Web Sockets and turn it "on" [image: Web sockets setting]
4. Success! [image: Angular Dev Log]